# AppleScript: Tell Application of Specific Instance

Tags: macos, applescript, instance

I have 2 instances of one application running (same application path) and I want to target one of them by their PID to run an AppleScript snippet. How would I go about that? I have the PID of the instance I want to target, but if I run the following, it will execute on whichever instance was started last, regardless of which is frontmost.

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2018/Adobe After Effects CC 2018.app" to DoScript "alert()"
```

Is there a way to get an application by PID and tell that one specifically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make a list of the processes running for the particular application(s).

*One way would be:*

```
set theApp to "Adobe After Effects CC 2018"

tell application "System Events"
    set processList to the name of every process whose name contains theApp
    set {processList, pidList} to the {name, unix id} of (every process whose name contains theApp)
    set frontmost of every process whose unix id is item 1 of pidList to true
    display dialog "Application: " & item 1 of processList & "
             PID: " & item 1 of pidList
end tell
```

This should switch to the first process of the application according to it's PID. Replace the `display dialog` line with whatever you want happening at that point on.

Comment: This gets me a list of PID's for that application, but what I'm trying to do is then tell that application to do something, if that makes sense. 

Replacing the `display dialog` with my command `tell application "/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2018/Adobe After Effects CC 2018.app" to DoScript "alert()"` still targets whichever app was last opened, not the one I'm trying to target.

Comment: What is `DoScript`? That's not an AppleScript command I'm familiar with; there's a `do script` command, although that is not used in a tell block usually.

Comment: `DoScript` I believe is specific to After Effects, not positive. I don't use AppleScript a ton, but seems like it's the only way to run scripts in AE from an external app without having a plugin/extension translate in between. Regardless, it should work since tell application `"/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2018/Adobe After Effects CC 2018.app" to DoScript "alert()"` works, just not on the instance I'm trying to target.

Comment: I see; this is a tough one since what is being used is the applications AppleScript dictionary which isn't specific to a particular process. So essentially what will happen is that even though you've switched focus to the first process the AppleScript dictionary for the app will run the `DoScript` on the newest process. I'm not sure of the best way around that just yet, although when/if I do I'll let you know.